# Odoo adds "postmaster" prefix to sender address

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Apparently, ODOO does add a "postmaster" prefix to sender address of outgoing emails (e.g. "postmaster-[user]@[domain]"). How can I suppress this behaviour?

Comment: I changed the section `postmaster = get_param(cr, uid, 'mail.bounce.alias', default='postmaster-odoo', context=context,)` to `postmaster = get_param(cr, uid, 'mail.bounce.alias', default='odoo',
context=context,)` in files `lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-8.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py`, `odoo8/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py`, and `odoo8/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py`. But unfortunately, those changes had no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing all catchall parameters (mail.catchall.domain and mail.catchall.alias) under "Settings" -> "Technical" -> "Parameters" -> "System Parameters" does the trick.

Comment: But how to use alias system for e.g. projects without these parameters?

Comment: It works like that. But it would be nice to know how this works in the backend. What are these parameters?

Comment: I'm glad you found the reason yourself since we are not using Odoo anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I found a mistake in the [source code](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py#L366). It is using `mail.bounce.alias` instead of `mail.catchall.alias`

```python
def _get_default_bounce_address(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    '''Compute the default bounce address.

    The default bounce address is used to set the envelop address if no
    envelop address is provided in the message.  It is formed by properly
    joining the parameters "mail.catchall.alias" and
    "mail.catchall.domain".

    If "mail.catchall.alias" is not set it defaults to "postmaster-odoo".

    If "mail.catchall.domain" is not set, return None.

    '''
    get_param = self.pool['ir.config_parameter'].get_param
    postmaster = get_param(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'mail.bounce.alias',
                            default='postmaster-odoo',
                            context=context,)
    domain = get_param(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, 'mail.catchall.domain', context=context)
    if postmaster and domain:
        return '%s@%s' % (postmaster, domain)
```

So if you fill the `mail.bounce.alias` should work. Anyway I had to modify a couple of things more in the source code to make it work as I wanted:

```python
def send_email(self, cr, uid, message, mail_server_id=None, smtp_server=None, smtp_port=None,
               smtp_user=None, smtp_password=None, smtp_encryption=None, smtp_debug=False,
               context=None):

    smtp_from = self._get_default_bounce_address(cr, uid, context=context)
    if not smtp_from:
        smtp_from = message['From']   # this is only for the smtp
    assert smtp_from, "The Return-Path or From header is required for any outbound email"

    # [...]
```

You can also modify the email_from in the `build_email` method. But you should fill the parameter `email_from` in the Odoo configuration file

```python
def build_email(self, email_from, email_to, subject, body, email_cc=None, email_bcc=None, reply_to=False,
           attachments=None, message_id=None, references=None, object_id=False, subtype='plain', headers=None,
           body_alternative=None, subtype_alternative='plain'):

    email_from = tools.config.get('email_from')

    # [...]
```

I think I didn't forget anything